# Is SVG practical for highly complex illustrations on the web?

Tags: image, web-applications, graphics, web, svg

I'm working on a web-app that uses quite a few large, complex images for backgrounds and for foreground illustrations. I'm leaning toward using SVG instead of raster graphics because of its scalability and the dynamic interactions it allows. But some of the larger images are very complex (several thousand paths, drawn in Inkscape).

How practical will it be (in terms of performance) to use SVG images of that kind of size? Will it make my page significantly slower than if I were using PNG images? Are there specific techniques (e.g., one embedding approach over another) that will make the difference in downloading and rendering speed?

Comment: Certainly it will be slower to render a vector graphic of that complexity than a bitmap, but whether it renders at an acceptable speed depends on a lot of things. Why not set up a web server locally, add an SVG image onto a page, and try it in a range of browsers? That will give an idea if the load/render times are okay for you.

Comment: I have developed this website which uses heavy masked parallax based background SVG but as i builted new section it started lagging like hell... i don't think SVG is good for complex layouts..

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the path data to fit your view port size.
Some invisible elements should not be output to DOM tree.
Google map also uses SVG and runs very well.

Comment: How would one go about keeping the invisible elements out of the DOM tree?